# Can you do a smooth scroll to bottom purely with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've like to put a link that says 'contact' up top, and then scroll down to my footer, where the contact for is, when it is clicked. I'm wondering if I can do this with pure CSS? Maybe with the :target pseudo class, maybe with transform...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: NO. Scrolling can only be triggered using javascript. You could use an anchor. But thats not what you want to do I guess. Using animate() you can just use the example of Louis Castro.

Answer (score 1):

you can view example http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/
I think can't use css to active it, just js....

```
// Cache selectors
var topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
});
// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
// Get container scroll position
 var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
// Get id of current scroll item
var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
   return this;
});
// Get the id of the current element
cur = cur[cur.length-1];
var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
// Set/remove active class
 menuItems
 .parent().removeClass("active")
 .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery as follow

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this trough jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('a#back-top').click(function () {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
    });
});
```